# MySQL UNION Statement to select two columns having a specific value and select two other columns having another specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched for this question on S/O but couldn't find anything.
What I'm trying to do is two select two rows containing a value plus two rows containing the other value.
Like:

```
Row1: val:1
Row1: val:1
Row2: val:20
Row3: val:20
```

What I though of was this:

```
SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '1' LIMIT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '20' LIMIT 2
```

But an exception is thrown which says

> LIMIT clause should come after UNION ALL not before

but I want it to exactly return two rows with the first value and two rows with the second value.
And I want the selection to be random too. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '20'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wraps the two portions of the `UNION` in parentheses:

```
(SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE valueforunit = '20' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```